# Save temporarily selected items from a list to a ExpandableList in a Fragment

Tags: android

Ok, so I am new to programming and I built this App that finds you words that rhyme with an input word.

First you enter the word, then you click 'search rhyme' and then you get presented the results in a new ResultActivity as a list with checkable words.

If you check a word (or more) a button appears that lets you save the selected words.

Then you can go back to the MainActivity and there in a tab (FragmentFavourite) you can look at the saved words.

*FragmentFavourite* is an ExpandableList with the original word as its head and the saved word as its child

There is some problem with my checkable items.
If I check one result click the button to save it in the FragmentFavourite, then uncheck it and go to the Favourite, there only appears the head,i.e. the original word, but no saved words.

If I check one result, click the button, and go to the Favourite tab, everything works.

There is some bug with selecting and unselecting the words I want to save and then save it, but I can't seem to fix it...

**ResultsActivity.java**

```
public class ResultActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //create an ArrayList object to store selected item
    ArrayList<String> selectedItems = new ArrayList<>();
    private String originalWord;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Results");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        final Button btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        btnSave.setEnabled(false);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        originalWord = intent.getStringExtra("OriginalWord");
        ArrayList<String> myArray = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("WordList");


        ListView checkableListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.checkableListView);
        checkableListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.rowlayout, R.id.txt_title , myArray);
        checkableListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        checkableListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String selectedWord = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();
                if(selectedItems.contains(selectedWord)){
                    selectedItems.remove(selectedWord); //uncheck Word
                    if(selectedItems.size() == 0){
                        btnSave.setEnabled(false);
                    }

                }
                else{
                    selectedItems.add(selectedWord); //check Word
                    //savedItems.add(selectedWord);
                    if(selectedItems.size() > 0){
                        btnSave.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                }

            }
        });
    }
    public void saveSelectedItems(View view){
        String items = "";
        HashMap<String, List<String>> savedWords = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        savedWords.put(originalWord, selectedItems);
        for(String word : selectedItems){
            items += "-" + word + "\n";
        }
        Toast.makeText(this,"Words saved: \n" + items, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = MainActivity.getAdapter();
        FragmentFavourite fragmentFavourite = (FragmentFavourite) adapter.getItem(1);
        fragmentFavourite.putArguments(originalWord, savedWords);
    }
}
```

I save the words I select in an Array *selectedItems*, then, if I click the button to save the selected items I call the *saveSelectedItems* method and pass the *selectedItems* to the *FragmentFavourite*

**FragmentFavourite.java**

```
public class FragmentFavourite extends Fragment {
    View view;
    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    List<String> listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    public FragmentFavourite() {
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.favourite_fragment, container, false);
        // get the listview
        expListView = (ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

        // preparing list data
        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(getContext(), listDataHeader, listDataChild);
        // setting list adapter
        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        return view;
    }
    public void putArguments(String originalWord, HashMap<String, List<String>> savedWords){
        listAdapter.addData(originalWord, savedWords);
        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


}
```

And then I pass the data to the Adapter to insert it the data

**ExpandableListAdapter.java**

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                                 HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

    //Add method to save results from ResultActivity
    public void addData(String originalWord, HashMap<String, List<String>> savedWords){

        List<String> temp = savedWords.get(originalWord);
        if(_listDataChild.containsKey(originalWord)){
            for(String word :temp){
                if(_listDataChild.get(originalWord).contains(word)){
                    continue;

                } else{
                    _listDataChild.get(originalWord).add(word);
                }
            }

        } else{
            this._listDataHeader.add(originalWord);
            _listDataChild.put(originalWord,temp);
        }

    }
}
```

The thing is, if I select a word and save it and go to the FavouriteFragment I, the listDataChild is first empty and then gets filled.
If I select something and then unselect it and select another word, the listDataChild is suddenly filled with the selected word without clicking the save button

So what I want is:
If I select a word in the ResultActivity and then click the save button, then unselect this word and select a new word, I want both to be saved and not only the latter one.

Can anybody help me with this?
Thanks in advance!